# Does YUI compressor support bundling of multiple files?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, dojo, yui-compressor

I created a moduling system using jQuery. Is there any build system something similar to Dojo's Shrinksafe, that could combine all my module files into one single file for production?

Does YUI Compresser is all about single file compression or does it support bundling the module files as well? JavascriptMVC uses a custom build of Shrinksafe. Any links or info on that direction will also help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) has [an optimization tool](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) that can combine multiple files together, and it uses Google's Closure Compiler to do JavaScript minification/comment stripping. The optimization tool was based on the work I did in the Dojo build system, but it is something that works more stand-alone.

Disclaimer: I develop RequireJS